# Creating a marker felt highlight effect

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create an effect that when a user hovers over text it creates a market felt effect it - exactly like done here: http://courtneycarman.com/

I want it to animate in the same way.

Any pieces of code to how to do this would be greatful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Next time right click, inspect element.
It's right there. But, if you don't know what you are looking for it might be hard to figure out.

The effect is accomplished by a `:hover` style that will only activate when the element is hovered. In this case it has a gradient background that is normally 'hidden'by a 0 size.
When it's hovered it's set to 100% size.

Then there is a 'transition' defined, that will take care of the animating effect.

```css
.semibold:hover {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.semibold {
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg,transparent 55%,#ffde17 0);
    background-size: 0 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    transition: background-size 0.4s ease;
```

```html
<p>here is some text and stuff<strong class="semibold">and this is semibold</strong></p>
```

Comment: Thanks this is great, I new I could inspect it but I couldn't work it out. Thanks so much!

Comment: Study css transition effects, play around with the different possibilities. Also might be nice for you to look into animations, to add multistep animations.